# Is it possible to add tooltip on hover to material ui autocomplete component?

Tags: material-ui

I am trying to display the descriptions as tooltips of items in autocomplete component of MaterialUI. Is it possible to add tooltips to items of "Autocomplete" component?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution! It is possible to add Tooltip to items of Autocomplete by adding Tooltip component under "RenderOption" property of Autocomplete component. For example;

```
  const defaultProps = {
    options: top100Films,
    getOptionLabel: option => option.title
  };
  
  return (
    <Autocomplete
      {...defaultProps}
      id="list-option"
      debug
      renderOption={({ title, year, ...props }) => {
        return (
          <div>
            <Tooltip title={`Too Old ${year}`} placement="bottom">
              <div>
                <Button endIcon={<Info />} component="li" {...props} fullWidth>
                  {title} - {year}
                </Button>
              </div>
            </Tooltip>
          </div>
        );
      }}
    />
  );
```

Comment: Thanks! It would also work with `InputProps.endAdornment`. The important part is the <div> as first child of the Tooltip.